# "Find Next" Functionality in RichTextBox: Include "Match Case"

Tags: .net, vb.net, find, replace

I know that this question has been asked loads of times, but I have a specific request. It might be a bit hard to understand, for which I apologize. I'll try and comment the code as best I can. If you need clarification, please tell me.

My problem is that I have very complicated, unnecessary code because I wrote it myself and this is a new concept to me. The code is intended to find a string in the main window's RichTextBox (the string is obviously supplied by the user). The code works fine, but due to its convoluted nature, I don't know how to implement a "Match case" function.

The form has these controls (at least the ones you use when searching for text):

- Textbox: `txtFind` - User enters a search term here
- Checkbox: `chkMatchCase` - Allows a user to choose whether or not to match the case of the search term
- Button: `btnFind` - The Find Next button

And this is my code:

```
Dim index As Integer = 0

Private Sub OK_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click
    Dim strSearchTerm As String
    Dim lastIndex As Integer
    Dim strLastSearch As Integer

    'Set the end of the find location to the last known instance of the search term
    lastIndex = frmMain.rtxtNotepad.Text.LastIndexOf(Me.txtFind.Text)
    'If the last known location is 0 (meaning the string is located at the beginning of the document), set strSearchTerm to 0.
    If lastIndex = 0 Then
        strSearchTerm = 0
    ElseIf lastIndex = -1 Then
        'If the search term appears not to exist, double-check (due to an error when searching using Text.LastIndexOf and the case of the search term does not match the instance):
        If frmMain.rtxtNotepad.Text = "" Then
            '   1a) If the main window's RTB is empty, warn the user
            MsgBox("Cannot find '" & txtFind.Text & "'.")
        Else
            '   1b) If the RTB is not empty, search again. 
            If frmMain.rtxtNotepad.Find(Me.txtFind.Text, 0, frmMain.rtxtNotepad.Text.Length, RichTextBoxFinds.None) = -1 Then
                '   2a) If the search string is not found again, warn the user.
                MsgBox("Cannot find '" & txtFind.Text & "'.")
            Else
                '   2b) If it is found, set strSearchTerm to the beginning index of the occurrence.
                strSearchTerm = frmMain.rtxtNotepad.Find(Me.txtFind.Text, 0, frmMain.rtxtNotepad.Text.Length, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
            End If
        End If
    Else
        'If none of the above apply, set strSearchTerm to the index of the occurence
        strSearchTerm = frmMain.rtxtNotepad.Find(Me.txtFind.Text, index, lastIndex, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
    End If

    If strSearchTerm = -1 Then
        'If the search term is found, but this is the last instance, loop back
        strLastSearch = frmMain.rtxtNotepad.Text.LastIndexOf(Me.txtFind.Text)

        frmMain.Focus()
        frmMain.rtxtNotepad.SelectionStart = strLastSearch
        frmMain.rtxtNotepad.SelectionLength = Me.txtFind.Text.Length

        index = 0
    Else
        'If the search term is found, and this is not the last instance, set the starting integer of the Find statement to bypass the previous occurrence of the search term
        frmMain.Focus()
        frmMain.rtxtNotepad.SelectionStart = strSearchTerm
        frmMain.rtxtNotepad.SelectionLength = Me.txtFind.Text.Length

        index = strSearchTerm + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Anyway, if there's a better way to implement this, please let me know. And I did extensive searching, but found no good solution. I ended up combining a bunch of little parts of other tutorials into this. If there's no better solution, I'd just like to know how to implement a "Match case" function.

Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any overload of [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3134f2f7.aspx) method that takes [RichTextBoxFinds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextboxfinds.aspx) option - it allows to matching by case on/off.

Your code can be a lot simpler. For example, assume that you have class/form level variable `LastFoundLocation` that stores the last found location. The zero value means search from start while -1 means search from current cursor location. So relevant C# code in the button handler would be

```
if (LastFoundLocation < 0) 
{
   // set it to current cursor location
   LastFoundLocation = frmMain.rtxtNotepad.SelectionStart;
}
LastFoundLocation = frmMain.rtxtNotepad.Find(txtFind.Text, LastFoundLocation, chkMatchCase.Checked ? RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase : RichTextBoxFinds.None);
if (LastFoundLocation < 0) 
{
   // Not Found
}
else
{
   // Found and word will be highlighted
}
```

Comment: That code is wonderful, thanks, but I'm afraid I'm using VB.NET. Oh, you said C#. My bad! I've converted it to VB.NET and I'm going to see if it works!

Comment: It works wonderfully, thank you! The only problem I'm having at this point is that I want it to loop back to the first instance of the search term. I'm trying to figure it out right now.

EDIT: It's working perfectly now! Thank you!